# Instantiated class with "new" keyword is null after Start method has ended and button is pressed. Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a SaveController, it looks like this:

[image]

In the Start method of a MainMenuLogic class, I instantiate an instance of SaveController:

[image]

When the game starts, MusicOn method has been called before the Start method is called so the soundController is null...

[image]

```
public void MusicOn(bool on)
{
    saveController.MusicOn(on);
}
```

I've obviously not understood the application flow, so wondered if anyone has an idea on what might be going wrong. Which method should i instantiate the SaveController?

*P.S I know, GameObject.Find, bleurgh... i'm refactoring, no wuckers.*

Comment: Please don't add code as image but as text to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip derHugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Awake was the method i was looking for.

`Awake` is called before `Start`, so doing the `saveController` instantiation in `Awake` allows for the instantiation to happen before `MusicOn` is called.

```
void Awake() 
{
    saveController = new SaveController();
}
```

source: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/awake-and-start

Comment: Also check out the Script Execution Order: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html

Comment: Another option is also wrapping saveController in a property that checks if saveController is null, then constructing an instance if it is and returning saveController.

Comment: Thanks guys. And you'll be happy to know i've removed almost all instances of GameObject.Find. :)